# Add string to html element for javascript parsing?

Tags: html, markup

I have a menu that is created dynamically with javascript.

First it looks for for section elements with a certain attribute eg:

```
<section something="add"></section>
```

And adds them to the menu. It also needs to get the title that will appear on each menu item from each element, eg:

```
<section something="add" something2="Services"></section>
```

I don't need any help with the js I just want to know how to add the data to the elements and what names give to the attributes. How should I do it?

Comment: You want to know how to add the `mtitle` attribute?

Comment: and what is `att` attribute?

Comment: It would have helped if you showed how you were creating the element!

Comment: Use [data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) in your markup.

Comment: I only need to know how to do it in the html, I already know how to select them with jquery.

Comment: First try to understand your problem and possibilities of resolving it..

Comment: How are you retrieving the menu items?

Comment: FOA you have wrong Semantics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be easy if we set an ID to section

```
<section id="sectionUniqueID" data-example="add"></section>
```

Then manipulate with [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute) and [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getAttribute)  .

```
// 'Getting' data-attributes using getAttribute
var section = document.getElementById('sectionUniqueID');
var example = section.getAttribute('data-example'); 
alert(example);
// 'Setting' data-attributes using setAttribute
section.setAttribute('data-example2', 'substract');
var example2 = section.getAttribute('data-example2');
alert(example2);
```

[`Working Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/V5BYa/)

**Reference:** http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood the question. See the other answer comments.

Comment: Update the answer after changing the question . see now

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I am doing for my dynamic menu items (note: i have no idea what language you're using server side.  I use node.js server side and jade for my client side templating).

Note that because you have not asked a precise enough question, I am not exactly sure what you need.  You say you want to add data, give us an example of the data you are working with.

Server side:

```
var user_id = req.session.user.user_id;
// mysql statement to retrieve menu items
mysql.query('select * from menu where user_id = ?',[user_id], function(e, r) {
  var menu;
  // r would be array of objects:
  // [{menu_name: "one", link: "http://foobar.com"},{menu_name:"two",
  // link:"http:otherlink.com"}];
  if (r.length > 0) menu = r;
  else menu = [];
  res.render('menu', {menu: menu});
});
```

Client side:

```
html
  body
    section#submenu.navbar
      ul#menu
        - if (menu.length > 0)
           - for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) 
              li
                a(href=#{menu[i].link})= menu[i].menu_name
```